# CSS Styles to only One Class

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Using Zurb's Foundation, I'm attempting to add my own styles to the navbar, which is working great. Unfortunately, Zurb's responsive navbar changes its look when the viewing container becomes smaller. When it does this, it adds a second class to the nav element.

Before responsive change:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
```

After responsive change:

```
<nav class="top-bar expanded">
```

My custom styles look terrible for this expanded navbar, and I was wondering if there was a way to only apply styles when an element contained solely 1 class and not multiple. I know it's very easy to only apply styles when an element has two or more classes, but can you exclude one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this selector for your style in css:

```
.top-bar:not(.expanded){
//your style
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One option is to apply those styles for `top-bar` within an `@media` rule that only applies them down to a minimum screen width. That minimum width would, of course, be the width at which the `expanded` styles kick in.